# System Design For Asynchronously Processing Large XML Files

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, architecture, queue, system-design

We are running a web application on **GCP** using **Django**. One of the features include **processing and saving the data in an XML file (provided by the user)** into the PostgreSQL Database. We are facing two issues at the moment with the current setup we have:

1. The task is **NOT asynchronous**, which means the user has to wait until the app has done processing and saving the data.
2. The application **times out** when processing and saving large XML files.

What is a **good system architecture** we can implement here to solve these issues?

***NOTE: We already have Redis + Celery set up, but we are NOT using them for this particular task.***

Theoretically, the answer might be as simple as; ***Use a queue***. But the key questions I have are:

1. How do I pass the file from the user’s local computer  to the queue? Should I first upload it to Google Cloud Storage? (***If I were to upload it to the storage, I guess I would end up facing the same two issues while uploading the file***)
2. Should I further break down the file into smaller chunks and then put it in the queue for faster processing? If so, then how?
3. Is Redis + Celery good enough for the task? Are there better tools available?
4. How do I ensure that the **entire file has been processed and saved to the database**? What if an **error occurs while the workers are processing the file**?

Comment: How large is the XML file? How long is the timeout? What is the network upload speed of the user's Internet connection? My guess at this point is the upload will take a lot more time than the database write. That means why waste your time trying to make the database update asynchronous when that portion will take a few hundred milliseconds. The key when designing something is to know what you need to accomplish and what you are working with. Using words like **large XML files** is not helpful. What is large to you might be tiny to someone else.

Comment: The XML file may contain up to 10,000 rows. The default timeout I had of 30 seconds was not sufficient to process an XML file containing 500 rows. Is it possible to pass the file to celery workers in chunks without having to upload it to Google Cloud Storage?